# Angular2 Form Validation UI with Material Design

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

Following the example from Angular's official documentation, I have come across a road block with .css when using `<input mdInput ..../>` from Angular Material.

Given .css from the tutorial:

```
.ng-valid[required], .ng-valid.required {
  border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /* green */
}

.ng-invalid:not(form) {
  border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}
```

I get the following design in my output:
[image: Error]

How do I fix the CSS from "bleed through" the text input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Material Input Component](https://material.angular.io/components/component/input) has a `dividerColor` attribute, which is more straightforward than customizing the CSS.

### Documentation

> Divider Color
>
> The divider (line under the input content) color can be changed by
>   using the dividerColor attribute of md-input-container. A value of
>   primary is the default and will correspond to the theme primary color.
>   Alternatively, accent or warn can be specified to use the theme's
>   accent or warn color.

### Example

```
<md-input-container [dividerColor]="passwordError ? 'warn' : 'primary'">
    <input mdInput formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required>
</md-input-container>
```